# Value error when trying to input spaces into list

Tags: python

I'm creating a program to create an x iterations of an anagram of the inputed word by the user. This includes using spaces to break up longer anagrams into multiple (often incoherent) 'words'.I planned to add these spaces into the list (string) which the shuffled inputted word is stored at index 'spaceIndex1 & spaceIndex2' if the program decides the anagram should have multiple words. however I'm getting a value error:

```
string: ['e', 'b', 'l', 'e', 'l', 's', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'l', 'j']
File "c:\Users\User\anagram.py", line 35, in <module>
    string.insert(string.index(spaceIndex1), " ")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: 5 is not in list
```

*Even though I input the word 'jingle bells' and therfore (as shown above) list string has index >> 5 it says 5 is not in list*

see code below, relatively new so any help / obvious mistakes pointed out are appreciated.

```
import random as rnd

#take input of answer word from user, and convert to list of characters
string = [*input("Input the word(s) you want made into an anagram: ")]
iterations = int(input("Input how many random different anagrams you would like: "))

i = 0
while i < iterations:
    #shuffle the list to randomise
    rnd.shuffle(string)

    #check length of string to decide how many words the anagram will be
    if len(string) <= 9:
        wordCount = rnd.randint(1,2)     
    else:
        wordCount = rnd.randint(2,3)

    #choose index for space characters depending on hwo many words the anagram will have
    if wordCount != 1:
        spaceIndex1 = rnd.randint(4,5)
        spaceIndex2 = len(string) + 1
        if wordCount == 3:
            spaceIndex2 = rnd.randint(8,9)
    else:
        spaceIndex1 = len(string) + 1
        spaceIndex2 = len(string) + 2

    #loop through shuffled string, find any spaces and remove
    for character in string:
        if character == " ":
            string.remove(character)

    string.insert(string.index(spaceIndex1), " ")
    string.insert(string.index(spaceIndex2), " ")

    anagram = "".join(string)

    #debug prints
    print(string)
    print(spaceIndex1)
    print(spaceIndex2)
    print(anagram)

    i += 1
```

Not sure what to put in this section ,first post

Comment: Do not modify a list when iterating over it. In your case use `string = [c for c in string if c != " "]` for instance.

Comment: Regarding your code: you typically don't need to post all of your code; post only the part which is relevant. See also [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert spaceIndex1 directly. There is no point in putting the index through string.index() since that method is meant to find the index of a string, which you already have:
`string.insert(spaceIndex1, " ")`

Also looping through a list (string being a list of characters here) and modifying that list during the loop, causes issues. Loop through a copy of the list instead:
`for character in string.copy():`

Comment: would I loop through the copy list and then still modify my original list as the copy will remain the same as it's not being modified? (thanks for poiting out my mistake as well)

Comment: Yes, exactly like you said it

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in how you use the .index() and .insert() methods, I suggest you to read the documentation, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index)
and
[here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), to understand them better.
However, to make your code work you just need to change it
into this `string.insert(spaceIndexN, " ")` (N is 1 or 2).

Because the insert method accepts as the *first* parameter the **index** where to insert the string and as the *second* the **string** to be inserted.

I changed the code as I told you and it seems to work. If I made a mistake or something is missing, please let me know so I can improve my response. I hope I was helpful.

Comment: very helpful, thanks for poiting out my error.